# How to make \rightarrowtail and \twoheadrightarrow longer?

Tags: arrows, lengths, commutative-diagrams, resize

I am typing out short exact sequences and want to use \rightarrowtail and \twoheadrightarrow, but they have symbols above them so they need to be a lot longer, like \longrightarrow. Yet there does not seem to be quick and easy way to do this. How can I make these kinds of arrows longer? Here is what I currently have, with the output below.

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
$$K\overset{\alpha}{\rightarrowtail}M\overset{\beta}{\twoheadrightarrow}N$$
\end{document}
```

[image: short exact sequence]

Comment: Clip part of the glyph, then define custom functions to repeat it (unfortunately it's that difficult.)

Comment: First question is [packages - Extensible injection arrow - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9859/extensible-injection-arrow).

Comment: Second question is [arrows - No \xrightrightarrow[a]{b}? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114233/no-xrightrightarrowab)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you added the tag <kbd>commutative diagram</kbd>, I think you could use [`tikz-cd`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd) package.

Off-topic, see [Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
K\ar[r, rightarrowtail, "\alpha"] & M\ar[r, twoheadrightarrow, "\beta"] & N
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]